# Ein Scherz-Video vs. Ein Scherzes-Video

Tags: english-to-german, grammaticality, article, grammar-identification

Normalweise wenn man Neutrum-Ajektive nach unbestimmten Artikel benutzt, konjugiert man wie folgt, order?

Z.B: (Nominativ) A great concert - Ein tolles Konzert.

Aber ich habe den Satz "A joke video" einem Übersetzer gegeben und er schrieb "Ein Scherz-Video" statt "Ein Scherzes-Video".

Was denkt ihr darüber?

Comment: _Scherzesvideo_ klingt ein bisschen wie ein eines von diesen (altertümliches) Genitiv-Komposita: _Feindesliebe_, _Waldesruhe_, _Manneskraft_ u.ä. Aber es kann nur scherzhafterweise so gebraucht werden :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Kurze Antwort

> - a *great* concert → ein *tolles* Konzert
> - a *joke* video → ein <s>*Scherzes*video</s> *Scherz*video

Im Englischen sieht die Struktur der beiden Phrasen gleich aus, sie ist es aber nicht. Zwar ist *great*, wie Sie richtig erkannt haben, ein **Adjektiv**, aber *joke* ist ein **Substantiv**. Das Gleiche gilt für die deutschen Entsprechungen *toll* und *Scherz*, was man bereits an den unterschiedlichen Strukturen der deutschen Phrasen erkennt.

#### Lange Antwort

*Great* beziehungsweise *toll* sind **Adjektive**. Adjektive werden in Abhängigkeit von dem Substantiv, vor dem sie stehen, dekliniert:

> - eine toll*e* Party (weiblich Singular)
> - ein toll*er* Film (männlich Singular)
> - ein toll*es* Konzert (sächlich Singular)
> - viele toll*e* Artikel (Plural)

*Joke* beziehungsweise *Scherz* sind hingegen **Substantive**. Deshalb können sie keine Adjektivendungen tragen, auch nicht, wenn sie vor einem zweiten Substantiv stehen oder Bestandteil einer Zusammensetzungen mit einem zweiten Substantiv sind. Folgende Beispiele mit dem zweiten Substantiv *Video* funktionieren also nicht:

> - <s>eine Scherz*e*party</s> (weiblich Singular)
> - <s>ein Scherz*er*film</s> (männlich Singular)
> - <s>ein Scherz*es*video</s> (sächlich Singular)
> - <s>viele Scherz*e*artikel</s> (Plural)

Außerdem wird in der Zusammensetzung nur der zweite Bestandteil, hier also *Video*, dekliniert:

> - mit einem *Video* → mit einem Scherz*video* (Dativ)
> - wegen eines *Videos* → wegen eines Scherz*videos* (Genitiv)

Comment: Deine Antwort ist ein bisschen komplex zu verstehen. Aber  Ich danke dir sehr. Ich werde mehr Forschung zu diesem Thema betreiben.

Comment: Hmm. Die Antwort ist meiner Meinung nach weit weg von der Frage. Hier wird mit "Deklination" argumentiert, wo gar keine ist. Es geht wohl vielmehr um Fugenlaute bei zusammengesetzten Substantiven.

Comment: @tofro, wenn Sie noch einmal sorgfältig den ersten Satz der Frage lesen, insbesondere die Stichworte *„Neutrum-Adjektive“* und *„konjugiert man wie folgt“*, dann werden Sie bemerken, dass es sehr wohl genau darum geht.

Comment: Nein. Ich halte das für ein x-y-Problem. Im Beispielsatz mit "Scherzes-Video", um den es eigentlich geht, ist gar keine sichtbare Deklination vorhanden.

Comment: @tofro, Sie haben offenbar die Frage nicht verstanden. Der OP denkt irrtümlicherweise, *Scherz* wäre ein Adjektiv wie *toll* und müsse demnach auf die gleiche Weise dekliniert werden, also *Scherz**es*** analog zu *toll**es***. Das denkt der OP deshalb, weil die englischen Originalphrasen mit *great* und *joke* gleich aussehen (obwohl sie es auch da nicht sind).

Answer (score -1):

Zusammengesetzte Hauptwörter im Deutschen erhalten in manchen Fällen an der "Trennstelle" einen sogenannten [*Fugenlaut*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut), wahrscheinlich, um in der gesprochenen Sprache das Kompositum zu markieren.

Bei der Schreibung mit Bindestrich wie in deinem Beispiel wird der Fugenlaut grundsätzlich **nicht** eingefügt. Wann bei Zusammenschreibung ein Fugenlaut eingefügt wird (und wenn ja, welcher - es kommen -e-, -s-, -es-, -n-, -en-, -er-, -ens- vor), ist nicht sehr konsequent geregelt.

Dein Versuch ("Scherzesvideo") ist ein solcher Fall, der allerdings absolut nicht gebräuchlich ist. Möglicherweise hast du dich an den gebräuchlichen "Kindesmutter" oder "Manneskraft" orientiert. Bei diesen Komposita entstand das "Fugen-es" wahrscheinlich aus einer früheren Genitivform:

"Des Kindes Mutter" -> "Kindesmutter",

"des Mannes Kraft" -> Manneskraft.

Ein Genitiv ist in deiner Zusammensetzung allerdings nicht vorhanden ("Des Scherzes Video" ergibt keinen rechten Sinn).